# Auto track count of referenced children

Tags: c#, mongodb

Let's say I have an object structure like this:

```
class A
{
    string Name;
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int classB_count;
}

class B
{
    string Name;
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public MongoDBRef classARef;
}
```

I also have a generic repository, where I implemented the most basic functions for saving and deleting records:

```
public void Add<TEntity>(TEntity item)
{
    _db.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name).InsertOne(item);
}

public void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity item)
{
    _db.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name).DeleteOne(x => x.Id == item.Id);
}
```

What is the best way of auto updating the count in an object of type A, if I add/delete a new object of type B, that references A?

Is the above class design good enough or are there better solutions for that specific problem?

We are moving from a relational database to MongoDB and although we were able to redesign the biggest bottlenecks, we had to keep some references. And since we have to access the count of children inside queries for class A quite often, I thought it'd be best if I add a counter to object A. We are still playing around with different design ideas, so it is possible that the above design is not a good one.

Comment: Why not just implement Count() in your repository?

Comment: I just updated the question one second before you posted your comment, good timing :P

We need to have access to queries like: x=>x.classB_count > 5000 && ...
Without count that means we would have to first query for objects of class A, that satisfy all of our other conditions and then filter the results based on the children count, no?